# TestCafe get "Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined" error on mobile Chrome emulator

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to test a mobile version of the website. When the window is resized it works fine. But when I enable the emulator on Chrome, it fails with the following errors in the console:

```
   Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined at HTMLDocument.L
      (https://test.com/_ui/js/app/base.339067918ae10592e7c1bdd951897313.js:2:300833)
          at HTMLDocument.dispatch https://test.com/_ui/js/requirejs.jquery.8a08312711bf508edda14a4e6a36ac34.js:5:43928)
          at HTMLDocument.y.handle     (https://test.com/_ui/js/requirejs.jquery.8a08312711bf508edda14a4e6a36ac34.js:5:41806)
          at l (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:10:9320)
          at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:3:19119)
          at HTMLSelectElement.dispatchEvent (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:3:13879)
          at e._dispatchTouchEvent (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:4:5319)
          at e._simulateEvent (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:4:8294)
          at e.touchmove http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/hammerhead.js:4:19116)
          at t.move (http://testcafe.local.test.com:1337/testcafe-automation.js:1:29523)
```

It failed after the first click of a button or dropbox. I can't reproduce it manually. My code is

```
await t.click(Selector('select[data-test-id="listerSortOptions-select"]', {visibilityCheck: true}))
const sortOption = Selector('select[data-test-id="listerSortOptions-select"]', {visibilityCheck: true}).child(option);
await t.click(sortOption);
```

or

```
await t.click(Selector('div.productLister-viewOptions-inner > a', {visibilityCheck: true}));
```

TestCafe version 0.23.3.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you provide more information about the problem so that I can find its cause:
specify the TestCafe version,
provide code that runs TestCafe,
send us a public link to your website or a simple example in which I can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with [--skip-uncaught-errors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-u---skip-uncaught-errors) flag

Answer (score 0):

Try `--skip-js-errors`.

If this does not work, I suspect the error is due to the fact that TestCafe is trying to scroll the window to get the 'big' cursor to be over the element that you want to click on: in this case I suggest you to report a reproductible sample to @mlosev